# Difference between "a rate" and "a rate of change"?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, terminology

I have asked around on various (related) posts to educate myself on the question given in the title and wanted to get a general consensus on what my peers think of the following:

> Is there really a difference between *a rate* and *a rate of change*?

I noticed some authors define a rate in the following way: *a rate is the ratio between two related quantities in different units*. From what I have noticed, the usage of the word *rate* and the phrase *rate of change* mean exactly the same thing but can be used differently in a sentence. For example,

> suppose a car's velocity is $25$ miles per hour

then maybe we could say *the rate at which the car is moving is $25$ miles per hour* **or** *the rate of change of the car's position with respect to time is $25$ miles per hour*.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that it is largely a matter of taste. However, I think the main distinction is that defining *rate* as the ratio between two quantities (e.g., $a:b$) is a very broad definition, whereas *rate of change* suggests that the unit $b$ in $a:b$ represents time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bey. I will leave this question open for a little longer in case anyone else has input. If not, I will accept this answer in full :).